# Settting up or creating Mobile layouts on an exisiting site with ASPX+Portal Templates

Tags: templates, mobile, layout, migration, kentico

We are currently on Kentico EMS V.7 but when our site(s) was created there was not any mobile device layouts setup. an out entire site is build around ASPX+Portal templates so we don't have the edit layout option on our pages. What would you recommend an origination like ours do in this case? Is there an import or migration tool that can be used to move the pages into a responsive design template (are these available out of the box or do they all need to be built?)

has anyone else come against this challenge with their site when trying to a mobile accessible site, if so what approach did you take to move your site(s) over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know Stackoverflow doesn't like to answer broad questions, but I'll save you some trouble and hopefully at least point you in the right direction.  I use to be in your shoes and I remember how frustrating it was trying to find resources to learn all of this.

You've got some options, but unfortunately none of them are magic bullets.  All of these options involve design and development time.  If you haven't already done the research to consider if optimizing your site for mobile users is a good business decision, then I would suggest starting there first.

#### Mobile Device Detection

Kentico offers [device layouts](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+page+layouts+for+devices) that allow you to change the layout of your site depending on which device a user is browsing your site with.  The technique it uses is called [device detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_detection), which relies on reading the incoming user agent string of the user's http request on your server and using that information to determine what to send back to the user's browser.

This process happens on the server side of your application and also relies on comparing the user agent string against a list of known user agent strings.  Kentico in particular uses the 51degrees library to accomplish this.  This has the drawback of not always having the most up-to-date user agent strings, so new devices won't be included in your list unless you keep it updated.

A big problem with this approach is that you wind up maintaining multiple sites and/or layouts.  If you uses Kentico's mobile device detection, then any time you need to make changes to a page template you will also have to change each of the different layouts for that template.

You don't have to utilize Kentico's device layouts functionality to do mobile device detection.  You could just redirect users to a different site entirely.  In which case you can still very easily run into the problem of redundant maintenance.

Yes, there are ways of mitigating these issues, but most web devs agree that responsive design is usually the way to go if you want to cater to mobile users.

#### Responsive Design

This is a client-side design paradigm that relies on CSS media queries.  I'm not going to explain how it works since googling ["responsive design"](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en) will net you plenty of research material.  The short version is your user's browser handles the adjustment of the layout by interpreting the CSS of your site.  This means you maintain one CSS file for one site and the client handles the adjustments for you.

Now the down side to this is that it takes a takes a talented web designer to do it properly.  There are many responsive frameworks out there that can help you out with this, but their appearance is pretty generic and will likely still require customization to fit your particular brand requirements.  Some more popular ones are [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/), and [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

I recently helped convert a large website in Kentico with a static design into a responsive design by rebuilding all of the page templates using Bootstrap and merging their stylesheets together so that the desktop version still looked the same and the mobile versions had a consistent appearance with the desktop version.  This process took about two months and required a lot of UX and content strategy in addition to visual design and coding skills to accomplish correctly.  It's not the hardest job in the world, but requires quite a bit of skill and time to do.

Comment: To add to what Jerreck stated, the device detection is a free version which is updated at the time the installer was released so if you want to keep it up to date, you'll need to subscribe to that as there are new devices released all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion there is no tool which will make (magically) your site responsive. AFAIK the only way is to redesign your site manually (new CSSs - maybe any UI framework, JS etc...)

Maybe you can still use out of the box features like [device profiles](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?mobile_creating_device_profiles.htm) and [mobile pages](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?mobile_creating_mobile_pages.htm). (But I am not sure how it works and if it is supported while using ASPX + Portal templates development models).